# What is a good hardware monitor?

Tags: windows, cpu, fan, temperature

Does anyone have a good freeware app for monitoring laptop hardware? Things like temperature and fan speed. I had one, but after a few weeks it wanted me to pay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [**SpeedFan**](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) is free and supports a [lot of sensors](http://www.almico.com/forumindex.php).
   There is also a recent [Beta update](http://www.almico.com/sfbetaprogram.php).

   - I think the non-pro edition of [Hardware Sensors Monitor](http://www.hmonitor.net/) is free too.
     Have not tried it though.
   - Some other interesting tools,
   - [**GPU-Z**](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/SysInfo/GPU-Z/) current version [v0.3.6](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/1665/TechPowerUp_GPU-Z_v0.3.6.html)
   - [**Real Temp**](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/SysInfo/Real_Temp/) current version [3.00](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/1325/Real_Temp_3.00.html)
   - CPUID's [**HWMonitor**](http://www.cpuid.com/hwmonitor.php)

<sup>while you have not stated your platform, I assume you mean Windows.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add [cpu-z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php)...  I am currently using speedfan and am fairly happy with it (not so great with my Dell laptop)